# generic stored procedures in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, generics, stored-procedures

i want to write a generic stored procedure in oracle .For example i want to take table name as input and then do maipulations on it.
I want to learn  some sample generic codes and the basica of writing generic stored procedures in oracle.
Can any one provie code snippets/ links to websites or other material for this?

Answer (score 5):

Generic = dynamic SQL, either "Native Dynamic SQL" (Execute Immediate) or the DBMS_SQL package. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm#i1006546

Ordinarily SQL statements are parsed when the procedure is compiled, however this is not possible if the table name is not known -- the table may of course not even exist at compile time.

Here are links to documentation on the topic, with examples.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm#ADFNS008

A word of caution -- do not use dynamic SQL if you can use static SQL. The flexibility comes at a price.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need the [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora9i/execute_immediate.shtml) statement for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) does what you want.